# PHP: Why does statically calling a class function inside the class itself resolve to __call and not __callStatic?

Tags: php, static

I'm trying to understand why PHP prefers **__call** to **__callStatic** when statically calling a function from within the same class, and I'v done some research about it and found some similar questions, but none actually answered the question in a good way.

Lets take the following code as an example:

```php
<?php

class Foo
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        echo "<strong>__call :  </strong>".$name.'<br>';
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        echo "<strong>__callStatic : </strong>".$name.'<br>';
    }

    public function DoTheThing()
    {
        Foo::CoolFunction();

        static::CoolFunction();

        self::CoolFunction();

        get_called_class()::CoolFunction();
    }
}

// Calling from outside ..
Foo::CoolFunction();

// Calling Something that will call from the inside ..
$instance = new Foo;
$instance->DoTheThing();

?>
```

the following code will result in this output:

```
__callStatic : CoolFunction
__call : CoolFunction
__call : CoolFunction
__call : CoolFunction
__call : CoolFunction
```

I have read somewhere that calling from inside an instance is considered to be a "non-static context" and thus will resolve to **__call** and not **__callStatic**
and that made sense until i tried removing the **__call** function which generated this out

```
__callStatic : CoolFunction
__callStatic : CoolFunction
__callStatic : CoolFunction
__callStatic : CoolFunction
__callStatic : CoolFunction
```

when **__call** isn't available **__callStatic** gets called normally and that isn't like a regular fallback for calling a non-static function statically because that would throw a 
*"Non static function called statically ..... "* Warning, but it doesn't.
I've tried using **self::** and **static::** and even **get_called_class()::** which is same as **Foo::** anyways but non work.

a temporary *hacky* solution would be calling **__callStatic** directly but that's not what I'm looking for.

Is this the intended way for things to work ? if so is this documented anywhere ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#87785